# Render Component if image src is valid

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to render an Image component, but before that I need to check whether the URL is not broken.

My approach is not giving any errors and the **onload** function is loading. Though, I assume I am doing (or not doing) the return of the component incorrectly.

Could someone advise what is wrong?

---

~UPDATE~
I even tried using a renderImage method to ensure that I am using the return() syntax...

```
    renderImage(mediaObj) {
        let image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = mediaObj.url;
        console.log("mediaObj", image);
        image.onload = function() {
            console.log("onload");
            return (
                <Image
                    key={`carousel_${mediaObj.media_id}`}
                    {...this.props}
                    mediaObj={mediaObj}/>
            );
        };

    }
```

and map...

```
this.props.mediaObjects.map(mediaObj => this.renderImage(mediaObj))
```

---

Here is my render method:

**render()**

```
render () {
    return (
        <div id="galleryImages_outerWrapper">
            <div id="galleryImages_innerWrapper" className="flexParent flexRowWrap">
                {
                    this.props.mediaObjects.map(mediaObj => {
                        let image = document.createElement('img');
                        image.onload = () => {
                            <Image
                                key={`carousel_${mediaObj.media_id}`}
                                {...this.props}
                                mediaObj={mediaObj}/>
                        };

                        image.src = mediaObj.url;
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your `map` callback is not returning anything, so nothing will be rendered. What `<Image>` component is this?

Comment: @Aaron Hi, I thought about that and that's why if you see my update I'm trying to fix this, but failing still. :/ Sorry, you want me to show you the Image component?

Comment: Your `return` from inside the `onload` event is not returning to the `map` callback. Basically you still have nothing returned in the `map` callback which is why nothing gets rendered.

Comment: Yes what is this `<Image>` component. Is this something you wrote? Or a 3rd party library? If it's a component you wrote I would just add your behavior to only render an image after its been loaded in there.

Comment: @Aaron Custom written. That was initially the idea, but don't you think that performance wise it would make sense to NOT LOAD the component at all if the URL of the image is broken? Imagine if there are hundreds of components. (Assuming you can't use a load more functionality)

Comment: @Aaron Sooooo.... any thoughts how could I fix this? :)
I'm trying to return the component in map, but fail so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`image.onload` is asynchronous, so if you want to check urls validity, you have to wait until all callbacks are done, and only after it render the component. Make a chain of promises resolving urls, and after all of them are resolved update the component state. Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6uqj03zL/1/) with working example:

```
componentWillMount: function() {  
  let promises = [];
  mediaObjects.forEach(mediaObj =>
    promises.push(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let image = document.createElement('img');
        image.src = mediaObj.url;
        image.onload = () => {
          mediaObj.validUrl = true;
          resolve(mediaObj)
        }
        image.onerror = () => {
          mediaObj.validUrl = false;
          resolve(mediaObj)
        }
      })
  ))
  Promise
    .all(promises)
    .then((values) => {
      this.setState({mediaObjs: values});
    })
},

render: function() {
  if (this.state.mediaObjs) {
    let images = this.state.mediaObjs
      .filter((mediaObj) => {
        return mediaObj.validUrl
       })
       .map((mediaObj, i) => (
         <span key={i}><img src={mediaObj.url}/></span>
       ))
    return <div>{images}</div>
  } else {
    return (<div>Loading</div>)
  }  

}
```

Comment: Thanks, an interesting solution. I'll try this and will get back to you. :) One question – Why do you setState after receiving response? UPDATE: Oh, you meant to map over images later, I assume. Not mediaObjs. Got it!

Comment: Hope, you'll get it! I didn't check if the code work. But I hope, you got the principle!

Comment: You deliberately put the promise in **componentDidMount** instead of **componentWillMount**?

Comment: It doesn't make much difference since component will mount before promises would be resolved. For a better usability you can add an `else` statement to `render` method with a spinner or a "loading" text.

Comment: I've just saw an error in my code. Fixed `this.setState({images: values});` to `this.setState({mediaObjs: values});` The main idea here, is to render images, just when all promises are done and `this.state.mediaObjs` (**NOT** `this.props.mediaObjects`) is set.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117021/discussion-between-roland-jegorov-and-lazarev-alexandr).

Comment: **Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined** – I get this. :/ Haven't really worked with this approach, any ideas?

Comment: From MDN: 
"If any of the passed in promises rejects, the all Promise immediately rejects with the value of the promise that rejected, discarding all the other promises whether or not they have resolved. If an empty array is passed, then this method resolves immediately." ---> Meaning this approach won't work. :/

Comment: No dice yet. :/ It seems I can't get the async passing of props to work. Will get back to this tomorrow. Still thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I've update my answer with the working fiddle. Some things regarding promises resolve were changed, but the principle remained.  Hope it helps!

Comment: Funny, actually I didn't sleep up till 5:30 a.m. to solve the problem, and I had a similar  approach — resolve all, then filter response.

Comment: Yes. Also I prefer using .map() over forEach and returning the promise. That is what I've done. Thanks, man!

Comment: Glad to help you! :) And yes, I agree, `map` looks better here.